# Android : Is there way to Play sequential mp3 files from urls without interrupt?

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am creating application that load sequential mp3 files from URLs. As i try it with initialize next mp3 files on completion of first mp3 files, but the problem is that, when first files complete, player take time to prepare or initialize the next mp3 files, yes I know that is part of the media player,it will take time to Prepare(For `prepare()` it may be long And for `prepareAsync()` comparatively sort time).

But , What i need that, when first mp3 files complete there playing, next mp3 files (From url) should not take time to prepare,as it should play without interrupt. I want to know , **Is there way to attach next mp3 files for buffering while playing current mp3?**, so we can playing it without interrupt.

As i tried also it with downloading next mp3 file in cache while playing first one. But the problem is that when complete first one, the second mp3 file may be not fully download(which is too poor for 2g connection). and player will initialize the part of the mp3 file which is downloaded. and player will play only that part of the downloaded files which is initialized(please correct if i wrong).it cause files corrupt. and it is not good performance at all.

I tried to cache next mp3 files while current mp3 played about 75% percentage, but in that case the mp3 files doesn't cached fully and it cause also files corrupt.

So please give me suggestion, how can i playing sequential mp3 files without inrerupt ? And batter approch to do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Just save all Urls in an ArrayList` and note the `current index of songUrl`. And add SekkCompleteListener to it.When a song finishes change the index and play it .And full detail tutorial is [**AndroidHive**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

```
if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }
```

**Where playSong is**

```
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnSeekCompleteListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener))

Comment: Thanks for answer,But, It will also take time between two mp3. Just i need that next mp3  buffer should attach to the current playing. When current mp3 playing buffer complete than , it should start next mp3 buffering, so that i can play next mp3 without ineterrupt (the time betwwen two mp3).

Answer (score 0):

Use [setNextMediaPlayer(mp)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)) API which is specially designed for your case. You have to prepare another instance of MediaPlayer during playback and set it as next. Then you will have no time waste between tracks. Basicly you have to use 2 instances and swap them back and forth.